# Error when trying to connect a web service with a database

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I get this error(s):

> error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.SqlConnection(string, System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential)' has some invalid arguments
>
> error CS1503: Argument 2 : cannot convert from 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'  to 'System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult'

This is my code:

```
public string NumeroFactura(string NoDeFactura)
{
        string DtsConnection = "ITLIGENCIA-POS\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = SSOLINVBASESQL; Trusted_Connection = Yes";
        SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(DtsConnection);
        Con.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter CMD = new SqlConnection("select * from INVE_FACTURAS_PRODUCTOS_ENC where NFACTURA='"+ NoDeFactura+ "'",Con);
        DataSet DS = new DataSet();
        CMD.Fill(DS, "DATOS");

        DataTable TableNFACTURA = DS.Tables[0];
        string NFACTURA = TableNFACTURA.Rows[0]["NFACTURA"].ToString();

        return "El número de factura es" + NFACTURA;
}
```

Comment: Think about what would happen if a malicious user can input some text into NoDeFactura and they put in `blah'; DROP TABLE INVE_FACTURAS_PRODUCTOS_ENC;--`

Comment: Just a thought:  it's common practice in C# not to capitalize the names of local variables or method parameters.  When you use title case (such as "DtsConnection") it looks like a class name or method name, and when you use all uppercase (such as "NFACTURA"), it looks like the name of a constant.  Using camel case ("dtsConnection", "con", "cmd", etc.) will make your code more readable.

Answer (score 1):

`SqlDataAdapter CMD = new SqlConnection(...`

should be

`SqlDataAdapter CMD = new SqlDataAdapter(...`

Also, look up "SQL injection" and "parameterized queries", you're doing something pretty dangerous.

While I'm at it, using `select *` (and `SqlDataAdapter` for that matter) to retrieve one row and one column isn't terribly efficient.  And you're assuming that you will get a row back; if `NoDeFactura` doesn't exist in the database, `TableNFACTURA.Rows[0]["NFACTURA"].ToString()` will throw a null reference exception.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `Data Source` or `Server` key. Your connection string should look like

```
Server=ITLIGENCIA-POS\\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = SSOLINVBASESQL; Trusted_Connection = Yes
```